# Find out android control type from ID

Tags: android, controls

I am working on android project and I am looping through each control within a layout to add to an array, I am then passing this array to a function that will loop through the array and do some event based on the control. Is there a way that I can determine what the control type is. As psuedo code it would be something like this.

```
    void getControlType(List<View> myControls)
    {
        foreach (List<View> control in myControls)
        {
             string controlType = getControlType(control);
             if (controlType == "Button")
             {
                  //do something on the button
             }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While its not generally a good design pattern, this would work:

```
foreach (List<View> control in myControls)
{
     if (control instanceof Button)
     {
         Button button = (Button)control;
         //do something on the button
     }
}
```